# Arp table on a multi switch vlan

Tags: switch, vlan, arp

Lets say I have **multiple cisco switches** that are all on the same **VLAN**.

The question is:

If I do "arp -a" on a pc that is connected to one of the switches.

Do I get the Ip and Mac addresses of all the pcs on the vlan,
or 
do I get the arp table that is only on the switch that I am connected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you would get only what is in the local arp cache for that PC, which would basically be any other device on the same subnet that the PC has contacted.

Comment: ok, so is there a way to get the mac addresses(AND IPS) of all the pcs on the vlan?

Comment: nmap (filler words)

Comment: For example if you are on 192.168.1.0/24 you could do nmap -sP 192.168.1.0-255

Comment: Thanks, I will look on to it.. 
But I need to develop it myself. 
Do you know how they are doing it? It seems by your example that they are just scanning all the ips in the subnet.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  If you want to develop it yourself, you could just loop through a range of ips and ping them, then retrieve the MAC address from your arp cache if you are on the same subnet.

Comment: And if I am not on the same subnet?

Comment: You cannot get MAC information from machines on a different subnet without querying a device which is on the same subnet as those machines.  MAC is a layer 2 address which does not get routed across different network segments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10828/discussion-between-lior-and-gregg-leventhal)